# APK alignment Verification Failed (Using APK Signer 1.8.5)

Tags: android, apk

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my android app.

Verifying alignment of "hELLO.hELLO_SIGNED_UNALIGNED.apk" (4)...

```
         50  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  (OK - Compressed)
        699  META-INF/AAA.SF  (OK - Compressed)
      1,414  META-INF/AAA.RSA  (OK - Compressed)
      2,100  res/drawable/icon.png  (OK)
      4,349  res/layout/main.xml  (OK - Compressed)
      4,681  AndroidManifest.xml  (OK - Compressed)
      5,576  resources.arsc  (OK)
      6,681  classes.dex  (OK - Compressed)
     44,829  assemblies/hELLO.dll  (BAD - 1 B)
     50,042  assemblies/Mono.Android.dll  (BAD - 2 B)
    501,715  assemblies/mscorlib.dll  (BAD - 3 B)
  1,822,767  assemblies/System.Core.dll  (BAD - 3 B)
  1,835,654  assemblies/System.dll  (BAD - 2 B)
  2,097,892  assemblies/Mono.Security.dll  (OK)
  2,252,613  lib/armeabi-v7a/libmonodroid.so  (OK - Compressed)
  3,504,099  lib/armeabi/libmonodroid.so  (OK - Compressed)
  4,770,732  lib/x86/libmonodroid.so  (OK - Compressed)
```

Verification FAILED

Comment: How did  you build it? Please provide more information.

Comment: Well, I created this android app using VS 2010 with Mono for Android. Build and Compile in a Release mode. Then, using this APK Signer 1.8.5, I tried to signed the unsigned application which is inside the Bin/Realese folder. Actually, Signing success but failed for Verification. Does this make you clear about my problem?

Comment: [link] code.google.com/p/apk-signer/

Answer (score 1):

After you signed the APK file, it was named `hELLO.hELLO_SIGNED_UNALIGNED.apk` (the suffix `_UNALIGNED` was a hint).

Then please go to tab `APK Alignment` and align it. It should be aligned and renamed to `hELLO.hELLO_SIGNED_ALIGNED.apk`. Then from within the tab `APK Alignment`, choose that *newly created file* and click <kbd>Verify</kbd>. It should be verified successfully.

Comment: So you FIRST align it and THEREAFTER you can verify the aligned apk. This is a little bit confusing, why is the button "align" is not displayed first and the button "verify" on second place?...

Answer (score 0):

You tried to sign the APK manually and did something in the wrong order. You can try it again but it is far easier and better to let Eclipse do it for you.

**With Eclipse**

In Eclipse, right click your project, and choose **Android Tools** --> **Export signed application**.

Please [read this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard) for complete instructions.

**With Visual Studio**

Xamarin.Android 4.2.6 introduced a Publish Android Application helper that is similar to the helper process in Xamarin Studio. To publish an application, the build configuration must first be changed to Release. Once the build configuration has been changed, select the Publish Android Application from the Tools menu. When you finally publish, Visual Studio compiles the APK, signs it with the key specified, and then runs the zipalign tool against the APK, all in one step.

See [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/) for complete instructions with screenshots and also instructions for Visual Studio pre-4.2.6.

Comment: Hello @Eran, Ive done this app with VS 2010. Could you please show me how to publish and sign the application using VS 2010?

Comment: I see you're using Mono, I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: That would be great! Ill be watching you.

Comment: Well well well, done successfully! But why is the output .apk so big? Its about 5.87 MB. The app just displays a text using text-view. And also, when I install the app, it won't open. It just flash for a second and immediately closed. As I run on the emulator, everything works fine. I now, have a problem with my device ie. Android 2.3.6 version. The API level I used to developed is 10. Is something more I forget?

Comment: This is my activity class code:

`using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace WelcomeAndroid
{
    [Activity(Label = "WelcomeAndroid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            TextView txt = new TextView(this);
            txt.Text = "Welcome Android";
            SetContentView(txt);

        }
    }
}`

Comment: An this my manifest.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="package.welcome" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
  <application android:label="Welcome">
  </application>
</manifest>`

Comment: That is an entirely different question :) please accept the answer of it helped you!